# With Float div not appearing side by side

Tags: css, css-float

I am trying to place two divs side by side by using float but it's not working. I could achieve it by using CSS flexbox but I specifically need to use floats.

Thanks for the help in advance.

HTML code:

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="first">

      <div class="txt">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
     </div>
      <div class="Img">
        <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/559/200/200.jpg?hmac=YMqBxDHO4-upCRoX_Ho2FNQg40ANP2MndFXD8sPsSAc">
      </div>

  </div>
  <div class="sec">

     <div class="Img">
        <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/559/200/200.jpg?hmac=YMqBxDHO4-upCRoX_Ho2FNQg40ANP2MndFXD8sPsSAc">
      </div>
     <div class="txt">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.main{
  margin:auto; 
  background: yellowgreen;
 width:100%;
}
.main::after{
  display:block;
  content:'';
  clear:both;
}
.first{
  background:red;
  padding:15px;
  float:left;
  width:50%;
}
.sec{
  background:green;
  padding:15px;
  float:left;
 width:50%;
}
.txt{
  max-width:350px;
}
.Img{
  margin:15px;
}
```

Here's an example of my code:
https://codepen.io/ANANTHUC/pen/eYWoqQv

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the tour first. Then read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for debugging details. Pictures with code-lines are inacceptable!!

Answer (score 0):

Just add `display:flex; flex-direction:row;` .main class.
So basically your code will look like:

```
.main{
  margin:auto; 
  background: yellowgreen;
 width:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row; 
}
```

Also you can now delete the `float:left` part from your .sec class.

Comment: Thanks for help.Can u pls tell me how to achieve this usig float

Comment: Well, Idk if that's necessary anymore if this method works. I tried it only with float but it doesn't allow it because if two div's are 50% of the container width the first div just pushes the other one below itself. The only way this will work I think is if you set up the divs width to 45% . Either way I don't know what to suggest you except of working with flexbox and applying the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `box-sizing: border-box;` property in both first and sec class. This property will make the div take exactly 50% of the parents width.

By default, the width and height of an element is calculated like this:

width + padding + border = actual width of an element
height + padding + border = actual height of an element

For more details: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp